# C#, using merge to update multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I wrote a code that will read in a CSV file and will parse the data and then will add the data into a Microsoft SQL server. The issue I am having is adding the right numbers to the right columns. Here is my sample data: (Yes I know this is not a CSV, I put it into Excel and copy and pasted it over to make it easier to read)

```
department  emplnum lastname    firstname   sum_reg  sum_ot      procdate
114            1       a           a         25320       0      3674419200
114            1       a           a           0         0      3674505600
114            2       b           b         9960        0      3673900800
114            2       b           b         10440       0      3674160000
114            2       b           b         14760       0      3674246400
114            2       b           b           0         0      3674505600
```

This is just a sample, there are a lot more values. As you can see, there are multiple rows for the same employee. I want my SQl table to have the columns department, emplnum, lastname, firstname and then 7 different columns for sum_reg, sum_ot, and sum_procdate (i.e. sum_reg1, sum_reg2, sum_reg3.... and the same format for the other two columns). If you notice in the table I posted, one person has multiple sum_reg, sum_ot and procdate value. What I want is to have the first values  of those three columns to go in sum_reg1, sum_ot1 and procdate1 and then is the next row is the same person, but a different procdate, it will put the next row of data into sum_reg2, sum_ot2 and procdate2. Then when it reaches a new person, it will do that for them as well.

This is the code I have written so far (it is not the full code, just the code relevant to what I am trying to accomplish):

```
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlConnection conn;
conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();
var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [TABLE] AS target USING (select @department as department, @employee_ID as employee_ID, @last_name as last_name, @first_name as first_name, @Day as {0}, @regular_hours as {0}, @ot1_hours as {0}) 
AS source ON (target.employee_ID = source.employee_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0} WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (department, employee_ID, last_name, first_name, {0}) VALUES (source.department, source.employee_ID, source.last_name, source.first_name, source.{0});");
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", record.department);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_ID", record.emplnum);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", record.lastname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", record.firstname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", record.procdate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regular_hours", record.sum_reg_a);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ot1_hours", record.sum_ot1_a);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I'm a pretty know coder and it is my first time working with c# and with Microsoft SQL server. Everything I have so far I got online. I'm having issues with my Merge statement, especially the end when it is not matched. I also am really struggling on how to keep the same row but a different column for each different sum_reg, sum_ot and procdate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting that syntax to do, but you can't do `SET {0}  = source.{0}`. You need to list out each column explicitly. Same on the insert.

Comment: I saw it as a similar answer on someone else's question. They were only updating one column but they used that as a sort of variable.

Comment: Be careful here. You are using pass through queries and AddWithValue. It will sometimes interpret the incorrect datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @user6451557 well I don't know what that other person was doing, but you can't do that in SQL server.

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about implementing what I am trying to do?

Comment: You need to list out each column individually, `SET department = source.department, last_name = source.last_name` etc. Same when it comes to insert.

Comment: but how do i implement the fact that the first procdate that comes in from an emplnum goes into procdate1 and the second procdate that comes in from the same emplnum goes in the same row but in procdate2... all the way up to potentially procdate7, if there are that many rows for that certain emplnum

Comment: You can't. SQL requires you to specify the column names explicitly. You'd need your C# program to do that logic. You'll have to keep a row counter and execute an update statement based on the value of that counter.